# Android Eclipse context cannot be resolved in return type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class

I have problems understanding *Context* I write a program to control my light, but I need to check if he  doesn't connect the wrong WiFi and then use a wrong IP. I try multiple options without a good solution. I look to a few earlier question about context whiteout success. If you need the full program I can send it to you, but I think this is enough code:)

The exact problem is by *getCurrentSsid(context)* **error: context cannot be resolved in return type**

```
//CLASS SENDCOMMAND

public class SendCommand extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONArray> {


static boolean WifiSSID;


public SendCommand(boolean wifi) {
    this.wifi = wifi;
}

//FUNCTION TO CHECK THE CURREN SSID
public boolean  getCurrentSsid(Context context) {
     ssid = null;
      ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
      if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        if (connectionInfo != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(connectionInfo.getSSID())) {
          ssid = connectionInfo.getSSID();
        }
      }
       if (ssid =="Room#2")
          return true;
      else
          return false; 

    }
//wifiSSID = boolean getCurrentSsid(context);

//send the command
@Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(tag, "Beginnen do in background");
    Log.d(tag, "Wifi is " + wifi);


    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get;


    if (wifi && **getCurrentSsid(context)**){ //HERE HE GIVES A ERROR getCurrentSsid(context)
```

Comment: sorry for confusion, I edited it.

Comment: Where is context variable setted? O_o

Answer (score 1):

There's no symbol with the name `context` in scope in your `doInBackground`.

A common way to pass a `Context` to an async task is to store it in a member variable and pass it in in an constructor arg:

```
private Context mContext;

public SendCommand(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

and then use `mContext` where a `Context` is needed.

Comment: I tried this before! Eclipse doesn't give errors, but my app constantly stops when I push a button to turn on the light....

Comment: 09-22 17:51:45.628: W/dalvikvm(15218): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ea76d8)

Comment: I don't see the mistake?

Comment: Start debugging crashes with the stacktrace. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this . Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java